# Putting a restart button in my Space Invaders type game

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I am pretty new to Java coding and I am pretty poor at it.
I have been struggling with trying to put a restart button on this code for ages and it is really annoying me.

Everything has been initialised and imported i just can't get it to work (sorry for poor copy and paste job)

```
public void init()
{
  click=0;
  s=0;
  setSize(300,400);

  buffer = createImage(getSize().width,getSize().height);
  bufferg = buffer.getGraphics();
  spaceship = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Boole.fw.png");
  shoot = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"wm.fw.png");
  eshoot = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"BOIMB.png");
  invader = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"Ho Chi Minh.fw.png");
  setBackground(Color.black);
  enemies = (6 + (3*(level-1)));
  left = enemies;
  xplace = 75;
  yplace = 0;

  try {
      String str = "SomeMoreTextIsHere";
      File newTextFile = new File("C:/thetextfile.txt");

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
      fw.write(str);
      fw.close();

  } catch (IOException iox) {
      //do stuff with exception
      iox.printStackTrace();
  }


  for (int x = 0; x < enemies; x++)
   {
    if (x%6 == 0 && x!= 0){xplace = 75; yplace += 25;}
    else{}
    ex[x] = xplace;
    ey[x] = yplace;
    goaway[x] = 0;
    xplace += 25;
   }
 if (level == 1)
    {
  main.start();
    }
}

public void run()
     {
       while (kcthegreat == 0)
         {
               try
                 {
                  main.sleep(80);
                 }


         catch(Exception e){}
if (s==0)
   {
  for (int y = 0; y < 99999999; y++);
  for (int x=0;x<99999999;x++); 
   }
   s++;
         if (newstage==1)
           {
              newstage=0;
              shot=0;
              click=0;
              levelstatus=1;
              es=0;

           }
         else {
         for (int x=0;x<shot;x++)
          {
            shoty[x]= shoty[x] -20;
            if (shoty[x] - 15< 0){}
            else
               {
            for (int z=0;z<enemies;z++)
              {
                if (shotx[x] <= ex[z] && ex[z] <= shotx[x]+25)
                  {
                     if (shoty[x] <= ey[z] && ey[z] <= shoty[x]+25)
                      {
                       goaway[z] =1;
                       score+=100;
                        shotx[x] = 500;
                        break;
                      }
                     else{}
                  }
                else if (shotx[x] <= ex[z]+15 && ex[z]+15 <= shotx[x]+25)
                  {
                     if (shoty[x] <= ey[z]+15 && ey[z]+15 <= shoty[x]+25)
                      {
                       goaway[z] =1;
                       score+=100;
                        shotx[x] = 500;
                        break;
                      }
                     else{}
                  }
                else{}
              }
            }
          }




         for (int x=0;x<enemies;x++)
           {
            int movex =(int)(Math.random()*40);
            int movey =(int)(Math.random()*40);
            movex-=20;
            movey-=20;
            ex[x]+=movex;
            ey[x]+=movey;
            if (ex[x] <0){ex[x] = 0;}
            else if (ex[x] >275) {ex[x] = 275;}else{}
            if (ey[x] <0){ey[x] = 0;}
            else if (ey[x] >375) {ey[x] = 375;}else{}
            }

        for (int x=0;x<enemies;x++)
         {
          if (goaway[x] == 0)
              {
                int att =(int)(Math.random()*10);
                if (att==1)
                    {
                      eshotx[es] = ex[x];
                      eshoty[es] = ey[y];
                      es++;
                    }
                else{}
              }
          else{}
         }

        for (int b=0;b<es;b++)
         {
          eshoty[b]+=15;
                       if (x  <= eshotx[b] && eshotx[b] <=x+25)
                           {
                                 if (y <= eshoty[b] && eshoty[b] <=y+25)
                                  {
                                    spaceship=getImage(getDocumentBase(),"boom.jpg");
                                    dead=1;
                                  }
                           }
         }
        left=enemies;
        for (int x=0;x<enemies;x++)
         {
            if (goaway[x] ==1 ){left--;}
            else{}
            if (left==0){newstage=1;level++;}else{}
         }
        repaint();
         }
  }     
  }

public void stop()
    {
    if(main!=null){main.stop();}
   }

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
update(g);
}



public void update(Graphics g){
    Dimension d=getSize();

Color Ground = new Color(0xFFCC66);
Color Sky = new Color(0x6698FF);
Color Grass = new Color(0x00FF00);

bufferg.setColor(Ground);
bufferg.fillRect(0,0,d.width,d.height);

bufferg.setColor(Sky);
bufferg.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

bufferg.setColor(Grass);
bufferg.fillRect(0, 200, 300, 10);

bufferg.setColor(Color.black);
bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD",Font.BOLD,10));
bufferg.drawString("Score: "+score,3,395);

bufferg.setColor(Color.black);
bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD",Font.BOLD,10));
int shotsleft = shot;
bufferg.drawString("Level: "+level,120,395);

bufferg.setColor(Color.black);
bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD",Font.BOLD,10));

bufferg.drawString("Cannon: "+shotsleft,220,395);

bufferg.drawImage(spaceship,x,y,this);

for (int x=0;x<es;x++)
 {
  bufferg.drawImage(eshoot,eshotx[x],eshoty[x],this);
 }

for (int x=0;x<shot;x++)
 {
   bufferg.drawImage(shoot,shotx[x],shoty[x],this);
 }

for (int x=0;x<enemies;x++)
 {
   if (goaway[x] == 0)
      {
       bufferg.drawImage(invader,ex[x],ey[x],this);
      }
   else{}
 }
if (es==200){es=0;}
if (dead==1)
{
Dimension q=getSize();
Color Red2 = new Color(0xF70D1A);
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;

bufferg.setColor(getBackground());
bufferg.fillRect(0,0,q.width,q.height);

bufferg.setColor(Red2);
bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD",Font.BOLD,25));
bufferg.drawString("HO CHI MINH INVADERS", 10, 25);
bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD", Font.BOLD, 20));
bufferg.drawString("Game Over!", 100, 50);

bufferg.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD",Font.BOLD,20));
bufferg.setColor(Red2);
bufferg.drawString("Score: ", 110 , 340);
bufferg.drawString("" + score, 110, 360);   


bufferg.drawString("Leaderboard", 95, 200);



    Button restartbutt;
    restartbutt = new Button("Play Again?");
    add(restartbutt);
    restartbutt.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    restartbutt.setForeground(Red2);
    restartbutt.setBounds(200, 350, 85, 40);
    restartbutt.setFont(new Font("Hobo STD", Font.BOLD, 13));



es=100000;
}
else{}
g.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);
}






public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) 
 {
   click++;
   shotx[shot] = x;
   shoty[shot] = y;
   if (shot==50)
     {shot=0;}
   else{shot++; score+=5;}
   return true;
 }

public boolean mouseMove(Event e, int xone, int yone)
  {
    x= xone;
    y= yone;
    if (x>275){xone=275;x=275;}
    else if (y>361) {yone=361; y=361;}
    else{x=xone;y=yone;}`enter code here`
    repaint();
    return true;
  }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your button does not have an ActionListener, so whenever you press it as I can see nothing will happen. For example :

```
JButton showDialogButton = new JButton("Text Button");
showDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // display/center the jdialog when the button is pressed
    JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Hello", true);
    d.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    d.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

What is an ActionListener and how it works you can find here: [How does an ActionListener work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885584/how-does-an-actionlistener-work)